# what's the difference between password and cipher?

Tags: synonyms

We usually use username and password to log in a website, can I use cipher in the situation? Or any difference between these two words?

Comment: Have you looked up both words in a dictionary? What did it say?

Comment: A "password" is a word or phrase which you speak to the guard at the castle to get him to let you in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We usually use username and password to log in a website, can I use cipher in the situation?

No.

> ...any difference between these two words?

Yes.  You probably know what a password is.  A cipher is an algorithm used to encrypt and/or decrypt information.  Your password (or any other data) could *pass through a cypher* before being transmitted in an obfuscated (less secure) or encrypted form over the internet to the remote server.